# Pagination with ordered data with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Using hql in hibernate we can do pagination on a table data using below, but below will return first 5 data records in the table.

```
 String SQL_QUERY = "FROM Order order";  
 Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);  
 query.setFirstResult(1);
 query.setMaxResults(5);
```

But how can i do the pagination on a ordered data on a table for example an ordered data set by a order_id ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking, but just add `order by` clause in your query, and calculate first result based on page. Something like this

```
String HQL_QUERY = "FROM Order o order by o.id";  
Query query = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);  
// page size 
query.setMaxResults(5);
// page 1
query.setFirstResult(1);
// page 2
query.setFirstResult(6);
...
```